# Crafting a behaviour of creating (writing) rather than consuming (reading)

Tags: user-behavior, gamification

Imagine a forum-like community, eager to read but reluctant to write content.
Please give  a sample of what you saw recently and treat as a good user experience to foster the behaviour of creating content rather than consuming.

Comment: It behooves you to demonstrate such an ability to make such a request.

Comment: I suppose Medium (medium.com) is an interesting case study of creating a publishing platform that at one point was very focus on lowering the barrier for people to create content, but now unfortunately is more interesting in how to build a business model around that. Also people talk about the world's most dangerous writing app (https://www.themostdangerouswritingapp.com/) as another interesting example of creating a different writing experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**B = MAT**

A useful framework for looking at what enables behavior is BJ Fogg’s behavior model. The model assumes that a **BEHAVIOR** is most likely to happen when a person feels sufficiently **MOTIVATED**, is **ABLE** to perform the behavior (for example, they want to go for a ride and they have access to a bike) and is reminded to perform it by a **TRIGGER**.

I would suggest looking at the following ideas -

**Rewards**

> In psychology, there are two concepts - extrinsic and intrinsic motivation. This means that someone can be driven to do something either by external factors, like the prospect of receiving a reward, such as money, or by internal factors, like the enjoyment derived from doing an activity.

Rewards are a powerful way to get people to change behavior. They don't literally have to be monetary rewards. Take StackExchange for example. Many users here are motivated to answer questions as they are rewarded with a score and badges. This is the chance for you to get creative and come up with ideas to reward your users when they post new content.

**Gentle Change**

> Generally, it's best to evolve a UI with gentle changes. Build on the user's existing expectations about your system - Jakob Nielsen

Don't expect that your users will start creating content overnight. So you can start off with a smaller goal, and build and evolve from user research, testing and feedback. For example, you can start off with cultivating a habit in your users to leave comments on forums. From writing informative and detailed comments, they can then be motivated to create their own content.

There's no right answer. But a good answer is to bring in new ideas in the form of small changes and test how your users are reacting to them.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, that's a very good point on my question. Looking towards behavioral psychology =)

Answer (score 1):

I not sure if my answer will satisfy you, because it is only slightly related. I know a community in which a user is forced to write constructive criticism in order to receive one. It is a site for people who want to improve their story telling. You can't add a new piece of your writing if you won't write enough constructive comments on somebody else texts. Additionally you getting as many comments as you write yourself. You also rate comments, so if somebody write something useless his comment won't count.

The system is not perfect. The user is forced to write comments on texts that are assign to him by random, so writing comments don't feel good, but... the prize is worth it and the rules are fair. The lottery ensure that you will get honest comments from people who don't like your writing. They are usually the best in spotting your mistakes.

On other websites it is really hard to get any comments, and if you get any then it is usually about spelling or grammar. On "pioromani" you are getting comments that are far more beneficial to your writing skills then buying Grammarly.

(You can always add your text on the site outside of this system, but then you will have to pray for comments, like on every other site.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes it is valid, though only partially applicable to my case.
I agree, it's a two-sided coin, in the case of such constraints users will start to find a way to abuse the system.